# Can't connect Emulator to Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I want to make an App Engine connected Android app, and I'm beginning with google's tutorial available here :
 https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_run_debug?hl=fr

First I  have eclipse 3.7 Indigo, App Engine plugin 1.6.1, and GWT 2.4.0, ADT 17,Android SDK 17,Win 7 Ultimate.

I did exactly as they did (registered into C2DM service, installed plugins, signed on in eclipse with my google acc, etc...)

When i create project,it  error :  tool\lib\Proguard.cfg (the file can't be found).
And i copied it from Android SDK 16 T_T,and it workly.
I can connect from GWT clien(http://127.0.0.1:8888/Bb.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997) to Google app engine(http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin )
But when I clicked at Connect button in emulator to connect with Google App engine - step f in guide  https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_run_debug?hl=fr  (i had sighed up with google acc), it  error, eclipse debug jump at code : C2DMessaging.register(mContext, Setup.SENDER_ID),I cannot do anything with emulator;

Any idea ? Thanks very much for help.

If somebody have a example sourcode project App Engine Connected Android,please share for me, I cannot find exam about it.

Comment: Picture about error : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/53418223.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoang, have you seen [this](http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/) session on Google I/O 2011? This is a very good demo with sample code. Please have a look and see if it helps:)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U
https://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io

Comment: I have read and donne follow it, and i have error above. I cannot find how to download source code at https://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io.           Can you help me check them? thanks all